# Is polynomial $x^{2n-1}-4nx^{2n-2}-2\binom{2n}{3}x^{2n-4}-\dots-2\binom{2n}{3}x^{2}-4n$ irreducible?

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

> Consider following polynomials:
>   \begin{align}
> P_n(x)&=x^{2n-1}-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}2\binom{2n}{2i+1}x^{2i}
> \end{align}
>   for $n\geq 1$. Can we prove they are irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$?

So first couple are 
$$x-4$$
$$ x^3-8x^2-8$$
$$ x^5-12x^4-40x^2-12$$
$$ \dots$$

For small specific values of $n$ we can prove it, for example for $x^3-8x^2-8$ we only need to check for linear factor, specifically for roots $\pm 1,\pm2,\pm4\pm 8$. With Maple I've verified more than first $600$ values of $n$ so far, all appear to be irreducible (using the `irreduc` function).

However for general $n$ I have no idea how to go about this, the Eisenstein criterion cannot be directly used, so I've tried substitutions like $P_n(x\pm 1)$, but it does not help.

**Edit:** Just out of curiosity, I have tried to change the polynomial a bit to see when it stops to be irreducible (again for small values of $n$, let's say to $100$) and I found it interesting that you can do quite a lot changes and it still remains irreducible. For example replacing the multiple of $2$ by other integers, or changing signs of the individual terms in sum, or even replace $2i+1$ in binomial coefficients with $2i$. What is going on?

Comment: Not sure if this helps but$$xP_n(x)=x^{2n}-(x+1)^{2n}+(x-1)^{2n}.$$

Answer (score 1):

For odd $n$ the irreducibility of these polynomials follows from a generalization of Eisenstein's criterion known as [Newton's polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion#Advanced_explanation) applied to the prime $p=2$.

When $n$ is odd the constant term $4n$ is divisible by four but not divisible by eight. Furthermore, [Lucas' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem) tells us that all the binomial coefficients $\binom {2n}{2i+1}$ are even, implying that all the other coefficients, save for the leading $1$, are also all divisible by four (and possibly by a higher power of two). These imply that the Newton's polygon consists of a single line segment from $(0,2)$ to $(2n-1,0)$. The slope of this line is $-2/(2n-1)$ implying that the line segment does not pass through any integer points other than its endpoints. By $2$-adic theory this guarantees that $P_n(x)$ is irreducible over the $2$-adic field $\Bbb{Q}_2$ and hence also over the subfield $\Bbb{Q}$.

The case of an even $n$ is more complicated but it may be possible study the divisibility of the coefficients by powers of two and again settle the claim.
For example the Newton's polygon of
$$
P_4(x)=x^7-16(x^6+7x^4+7x^2+1)
$$
is the line segment from $(0,4)$ to $(7,0)$, has slope $-4/7$, and the same argument goes through.

Comment: I suspect that [Kummer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer%27s_theorem) comes in handy for the study of even $n$. Gotta go. Hopefully someone can take it from here.

Comment: Very nice, I will have to study more the $p$-adic theory to see why this guarantees the result, do you know of some good literature for this? Also if I understood correctly, the very first even case $P_2(x)=x^3-8x^2-8$ leads to line segment from $(0,3)$ to $(3,0)$ which passes through some integer points, maybe this might make this method difficult for solving generic even case...

Comment: I, too, noticed that this argument doesn't apply to $P_2$. I'd guess that there are other similar cases.

Comment: For example with $P_8$ we get a line segment from $(0,5)$ to $(15,0)$. This passes through $(3,4)$, $(6,3)$, $(9,2)$ and $(12,1)$ leaving irreducibility in doubt.

Comment: I have tried to find all even $n$'s for which this works, see my answer. Hopefully it is correct, although even then there are still infinitely many $n$'s to go...

Answer (score 1):

Based on @JyrkiLahtonen's answer which proves the irreducibility for odd $n$ and suggests path or even $n$, I was able to prove the statement for even $n$'s for which the Newton polygon's method works, although it still leaves infinity of even $n$'s to check (hopefully someone can bring another idea to solve these as well).

The Newton polygons method seems to work for even $n$'s for which $(2n-1,v_2(4n))=1$, so $
n=4,6,10,12,16,18,20,22,\dots
$.

First, we need to show that the Newton's polygon for $P_n(x)$ is indeed a line segment between the end points. For this it is sufficient to show that $v_2(2\binom{2n}{2i+1}) \geq v_2(4n)$ for $i=0,1,\dots,n-1$ (in other words every $y$ coordinate in the Newton polygon will be at least as large as the $y$ coordinate corresponding to the constant coefficient $4n$) . This can be written as $v_2(\binom{2n}{2i+1}) \geq v_2(2n)$. But this follows almost immediately if we notice that  $(2i+1)\binom{2n}{2i+1}=2n\binom{2n-1}{2i}$, and so by applying the $v_2$ on both sides (using that $2i+1$ is odd) we get
$$
v_2\left(\binom{2n}{2i+1}\right) = v_2\left(2n\binom{2n-1}{2i}\right) \geq v_2(2n).
$$

Finally because the constant coefficient is $-4n$ and leading coefficient is $1$, the end points of the Newton polygon are $(0,v_2(4n))$ and $(2n-1,0)$, and so the method will guarantee irreducibility for $(2n-1,v_2(4n))=1$.

Comment: Looks good to me.